# Can a package access the scope of where it was imported from?

Tags: python

Consider this

```
# file1.py
file1_variable = "something"
import file2

# file2.py
print(file1_variable)
```

Is this possible? If it is, how to do it?

Clearly `globals` and `locals` of `file2.py` don't contain `file1.py` variables

Advanced example I am aiming for:

**File structure:**

```
- file1.py
- my_package/
  - __init__.py

# file1.py
file1_variable = "something"
import my_package

# my_package/__init__.py
# Do something to get all variables from file1.py, I dont know what
print(locals()) # Should print file1_variable among others
```

Comment: `from file1 import file1_variable`

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I want to do it programmatically - have `file2` load all the variables of `file1` without knowing its' name or location. Also without a circular import

Comment: You can't access the variables from `file1` without importing it. There's no way around a circular import. Whatever you're trying to do here - stop and reconsider. Also read about the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: If you want to load all names, then use `from file1 import *`. Not sure what's bad about a circular import in this case. If you have a particular reason to avoid it, you should specify that in your question, so that you can get better answers for you specific use case

Comment: Think about it -- a package can be `import`ed more than once, but its code only gets evaluated a single time (as a reference to the module is created after the first import). So if what you were asking for *was* possible, the import order between your packages would change their behavior -- which would be extremely fragile behavior.

Comment: (Also, what you're asking for violates the Zen of Python. "Explicit is better than implicit", after all; if this kind of magic were widespread, it would make static-analysis tools useless -- and even *without* being widespread, it would make static analysis tools useless *for your project*, which is a consequence you should seriously consider the impact of).

Comment: If you want an equivalent of "locals" for modules, then you can use: `vars(file1)` or `dir(file1)` (after importing it, of course)

Comment: ...to be clear: I'm not saying this *can't* be done; I'm saying it *shouldn't* be done. Python has enough introspection capabilities that you certainly *can* reach into your calling stack frames -- albeit only for the first time your module is imported due to the caching described above, unless you're also clearing yourself from the module cache -- but if you do that, you'll be subject to the bugs/limitations described above.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy its for education purporses. I am deeply interested in how it can be done. i know its not a sane thing to do in a real project